# How to convert String to Float array Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have array of floats written to a file. I need to read contents of this file and pass it as argument to another function. The problem is that on read from a file I receive a String. How do I convert from String to [Float]?

This is how I read from file:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = "/pathToFile"
file = open(filePath, "r")

rawString = file.read()
#rawString is like '[569.675049, 706.275879, 776.753418, 785.674805]'

#somehow process rawString
processedArray = process(rawString)

plt.plot(processedArray)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have access to the NumPy library? Because it has useful functions to read in data

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I do have access to this lib.

Comment: [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) might be useful